# To get unique combination on the basis of 2 Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In Sql Server 2008,
       I have 3 columns in a table. suppose data is like this in that table.

```
Invoice      ID1          ID2      Count
149          281          318       0
149          281          346       0
149          318          281       0
149          318          346       0
149          346          281       0
149          346          318       0
```

Now, I want unique combination as result whatever the combination comes as ID2-ID1 or ID1-ID2, both can be treated as one unique combination. In the above example I need result as:

```
Invoice   ID1      ID2     Count
149       281      318      2
149       281      346      2
149       318      346      2
```

Thanks in Advance!
Vicky

Answer (score 2):

Just `GROUP BY` the lesser, greater of those two columns:

```
SELECT 
    Invoice, 
    CASE WHEN ID1 < ID2 THEN ID1 ELSE ID2 END AS ID1,
    CASE WHEN ID1 < ID2 THEN ID2 ELSE ID1 END AS ID2,
    COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY
    Invoice,
    CASE WHEN ID1 < ID2 THEN ID1 ELSE ID2 END,
    CASE WHEN ID1 < ID2 THEN ID2 ELSE ID1 END
```